# Configuration of Django + MongoDB + Python3

Tags: python, django, mongodb, python-3.x, nginx

We have started a project and we are building our environment with Django 1.6 NoSQL, MongoDB, Python 3.3, and the Nginx server. We are working with virtualenv too to isolate the environment for other projects.

We haven't worked before with these technologies, and we are having some issues in the configuration. When we try to run the Django server with:

> python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

We are getting these errors:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1020a55d0>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user_name/Development/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 93, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)

  File "/Users/user_name/Development/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Users/user_name/Development/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors
    from django.db import models, connection
  File "/Users/user_name/Development/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/user_name/Development/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/user_name/Development/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/user_name/Development/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Users/user_name/Development/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/user_name/Development/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 265
    raise ImproperlyConfigured, exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For what we have browsed, it seems that's because django_mongodb_engine isn't compatible with Python 3.3.

Any clue about how to work with Django, Mongodb and Python 3.3?

If that's not possible, we are open to any suggestion about which is the best option for make it run or about other frameworks that maybe we don't know and are good too.

--EDIT:
We have used mongoengine instead of django_mongodb_engine that works with Python 3.3 and this has solved this part.

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Why specifically can't you use Python 2.7, if the library you want to use isn't compatible with 3?

Comment: We would like to work with Python 3, which is supposed to be a stable version in order to not have to port the project to Python 3  in the future.

Comment: django-mongodb-engine depends on Django-nonrel, which is a modified version of Django 1.5 - which does not properly support Python 3 yet. There are a whole range of dependencies you'd need to port to make this work. You'd be better off sticking to Python 2 for now, if you want to use these technologies.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your replies. We have been looking for another alternative, and finally we have found that we can work with mongoengine that supports Python 3 instead of django-mongodb-engine. And also Django 1.7, with this approach we would not have to make the migration to Python 3 in the future.

Comment: We have now another issue with the new environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952145/django-mongoengine-unable-to-connect-to-mongodb where we have found some issues when trying to connect with the database.