# Django Mongoengine unable to connect to MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, settings, mongoengine

We have build our environment using `Django 1.7`, `Mongoengine 0.8.7`, `MongoDB 2.4.7` and `Python 3.4`.

We have installed [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) , but when we try to run the example of the website, we get the following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /users/

settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Request Method:         GET
Request URL:         http://localhost:8000/users/
Django Version:         1.7
Exception Type:         ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:         

settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Exception Location:         /Users/user_name/Development/projects/current_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py in complain, line 18
Python Executable:         /Users/user_name/Development/projects/current_project/bin/uwsgi
Python Version:         3.4.1
Python Path:         

['.',
'',
'/Users/user_name/Development/projects/current_project/lib/python34.zip',
'/Users/user_name/Development/projects/current_project/lib/python3.4',
'/Users/user_name/Development/projects/current_project/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
'/Users/user_name/Development/projects/current_project/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
'/Users/user_name/Development/projects/current_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

This is what we have changed in our `settings.py` according to the documentation that we have found:

```
import mongoengine

DATABASES = {
    'default': { 
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
  }
}

mongoengine.connect('database_name', username='root', password='password')


SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'
```

For what we have seen, if we connect through the `mongoengine.connect` method the ENGINE parameter should not be ignored, but we are finding this error instead. Anyone knows how we could solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, we have found how to solve the issue.

Instead of following the example that can be found on the http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ we have followed the [Quickstart guide](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart). Following this guide, we have solved our problem.

Many thanks for all the answers!

Comment: Hi @Bedros, I'm sorry but no. If we find the way, we will let you know.

Answer (score 4):

I used mongodb setting at the end of settings.py file like this

```
# Mongodb settings

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)

MONGO_DATABASE_NAME = 'prod'


MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'

from mongoengine import connect
connect(MONGO_DATABASE_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)
```

maybe this help you.